# Cannot get values via POST

Tags: php

I have written an electronic payment module for a bank. I was using it in a server without any problem. Now I'm trying to use it in another server and the problem is after payment in bank website, in my callback function I can't get any value(referenceId,...). Indeed `print_r($_POST)` returns an empty array.

Is there any special reason to not get POST values from another server? 
The bank of course uses ssl. but I don't.

Comment: What language is the POST data sent in? Is it a standard form submission, is it submitted via AJAX, does a server-side script send the POST data? If it's AJAX, then switching servers may be blocking your communication since browsers don't by default allow this type of transmission. You can however setup a hostname acceptance header in your PHP for the other domain.

Comment: take a look in the server logs, to see if the remote end is POSTING or GETTING your form..